# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'statistics'. Spring.IO

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, maven, youtube-api

i'm coding this API to get some details with the YoutubeAPI v3 and post it to a DB.

At the moment i have this error when i'm creating a table:

```
2015-09-08 11:22:40.795 ERROR 11384 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table ccccVideoDetailsItems (dbid numeric(19,0) identity not null, etag varchar(255), id varchar(255), kind varchar(255), statistics numeric(19,0), primary key (dbid))
2015-09-08 11:22:40.795 ERROR 11384 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'statistics'.
```

And i got almost no hair left on my head  because i cannot find the problem.

I have these three classes for retrieving each object. 
VideoDetailsContent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ccccVideoDetailsContent")
public class VideoDetailsContent {
    @Id
    private String kind;
    private String etag;


    @OneToOne
    @Transient
    private List<DetailsContentItem> items;

    public VideoDetailsContent() {
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public String getEtag() {
        return etag;
    }

    public void setEtag(String etag) {
        this.etag = etag;
    }

    public List<DetailsContentItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<DetailsContentItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

DetailsContentItem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ccccVideoDetailsItems")
public class DetailsContentItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "dbid")
    private Long dbId;

    private String kind;
    private String etag;
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

//    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "sID")
    @OneToOne
    VideoStatistics statistics;

    public DetailsContentItem() {
    }

    public Long getDbId() {
        return dbId;
    }

    public void setDbId(Long dbId) {
        this.dbId = dbId;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public String getEtag() {
        return etag;
    }

    public void setEtag(String etag) {
        this.etag = etag;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public VideoStatistics getStatistics() {
        return statistics;
    }

    public void setStatistics(VideoStatistics statistics) {
        this.statistics = statistics;
    }
}
```

VideoStatistics:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ccccVideoStatistics")
public class VideoStatistics {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    private long viewCount;
    private long likeCount;
    private long dislikeCount;
    private long favoriteCount;
    private long commentCount;

    public VideoStatistics() {
    }

    public VideoStatistics(long id, long viewCount, long likeCount, long dislikeCount, long favoriteCount, long commentCount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.viewCount = viewCount;
        this.likeCount = likeCount;
        this.dislikeCount = dislikeCount;
        this.favoriteCount = favoriteCount;
        this.commentCount = commentCount;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getViewCount() {
        return viewCount;
    }

    public void setViewCount(long viewCount) {
        this.viewCount = viewCount;
    }

    public long getLikeCount() {
        return likeCount;
    }

    public void setLikeCount(long likeCount) {
        this.likeCount = likeCount;
    }

    public long getDislikeCount() {
        return dislikeCount;
    }

    public void setDislikeCount(long dislikeCount) {
        this.dislikeCount = dislikeCount;
    }

    public long getFavoriteCount() {
        return favoriteCount;
    }

    public void setFavoriteCount(long favoriteCount) {
        this.favoriteCount = favoriteCount;
    }

    public long getCommentCount() {
        return commentCount;
    }

    public void setCommentCount(long commentCount) {
        this.commentCount = commentCount;
    }
}
```

The APIs Output is:

```
{
kind: "youtube#videoListResponse",
etag: ""sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/15jlenwUohs80IG8APFsDfw7xb8"",
pageInfo: {
totalResults: 1,
resultsPerPage: 1
},
items: [
{
kind: "youtube#video",
etag: ""sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/sCA7RDne1nKYHc3Fiqawl_oS3sk"",
id: "g_AT2djYGmA",
statistics: {
viewCount: "149353",
likeCount: "2369",
dislikeCount: "21",
favoriteCount: "0",
commentCount: "251"
}
}
]
}
```

Why the devilish, am i getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the brainlagg when i wrote the code.

So i fixed the problem by refactor the VideoStatistics class.

Setting all the input to String instead of Long since i got a string from the Youtube api.